# Why does yii2 mongodb date filter returns no results when using between condition

Tags: mongodb, yii2, yii2-model, php-mongodb

I am using yii2 mongodb latest version, when i try to get record in a given date range i get null records. my codes are as follow

Function that filter records received today that is in my model

```
 public function today(){
    $finder = self::find();        
    $startDay = strtotime('midnight',time())-1;//start of day
    $endDay   = time(); //now
    $d1=to_isoDate($startDay);
    $d2=to_isoDate($endDay);         
    $args=['created_at'=>['$gte'=>$d1,'$lte'=>$d2]]; 

    $finder->andWhere($args);
    return $finder;
  }
```

Function that converts time-stamp to UTCDateTime, when inserting to collection or create a query i call this function

```
function to_isoDate($timestamp){
   return new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($timestamp);
}
```

Trying to get all models that were created today returns nothing yet i have records for the day
One of the mongo document is as follow

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5892deb01c80f22a180af457"), 
"title" : "TEST", 
"content" : "we are", 
"slug" : "test", 
"guid" : "5892deae76036", 
"type" : "sms_outbox", 
"mime" : ObjectId("5891ae441c80f24e4057f332"), 
"meta" : {
    "from" : "5891d0a51c80f2131d327b92", 
    "scheduled" : "0"
}, 
"alias" : "+254723681977", 
"parent" : "5891ae071c80f2394e688db5", 
"status" : "sent", 
"created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-01T07:24:30.000+0000"), 
"updated_at" : ISODate("2017-02-02T07:24:30.000+0000"), 
"updated_by" : "588899ac1c80f227512d1102", 
"created_by" : "588899ac1c80f227512d1102"
}
```

Kindly assist to troubleshoot what am doing wrong

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue today, multiplying the `$timestamp` by 1000 resolved the issue and the date filter works fine now.

Here is the modified `to_isoDate` method:

```
function toIsoDate($timestamp){
   return new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($timestamp * 1000);
}
```

You also need to modify your query to look like this:

```
public function today(){
    $finder = self::find();        
    $startDay = strtotime('midnight',time())-1;//start of day
    $endDay   = time(); //now
    $d1= toIsoDate($startDay);
    $d2= toIsoDate($endDay);         
    $finder->andWhere(['>=', 'created_at', $d1]);
    $finder->andWhere(['<=', 'created_at', $d2]);
    return $finder;
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/issues/181

I hope this helps someone, I spent quite some time trying to find a solution to this.